# Почему при конвертации milliseconds в date выдает ошибки?

Tags: php, datetime

В чем здесь ошибка?

Пробую разные варианты, везде неверно выдает время, цифр 13, вроде и должно быть

```
$time = 1661990401854;
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $time);
// 19.05.54636 03:30:54

$time = 1661990401854;
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $time / 1000);
// Deprecated</b>:  Implicit conversion from float 1661990401.854 to int loses precision

$time = 1661990401854;
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $time * 1000);
// 31.03.52668349 14:00:00
```

Comment: Попробуй так $date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', (int) ($time / 1000))

Comment: @Danil Apsadikov спасибо, работает, забыл что приделении может быть остаток, второй вариант был почти верный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделите ваш timestamp на 1000 и округлите

```php
$time = 1661990401854;
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', round($time / 1000));
```

Comment: @NowhereMan Извиняюсь. Вы правы :) Отредактировал